# Send RAW network packets in Delphi (WinPCap)

Tags: sockets, delphi, pcap, winpcap

I'd like to send RAW network packets from our Delphi application (XE3 to XE5, if important), but I can't find any info whatsoever about using PCap in Delphi at all.

How would one do that?

There is one Magenta library (sockmon and sockstat, monitoring and statistics library for observing raw incoming packets on selected interface), which works nice for receiving RAW packets, however there is no option to send RAW packets out.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to figure out how to import the PCAP Write functions and invoke them. There is a PCAP.NET for C# that does wrap those.

Look at the SendBuffer sample code in the C# wrapper. 

https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/blob/master/PcapDotNet.DevelopersPack/src/SendingPacketsUsingSendBuffer/Program.cs

Something this rare, I bet you'll be one of the first people to ever do this from Delphi.

Comment: I secretly hoped to get a different answer than your last sentence, but... ok, I guess... thanks for your info. I'll try to dig into C# part... :/

Comment: PCAP is intended for *receiving* packets, not *sending* packets. However, the Windows port of PCAP, [WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org), does provide [sending capabilities](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html). WinPCap provides a [public API](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html) via DLL functions (`wpcap.dll`), which you can declare in your Delphi code like any other DLL. Or find a 3rd party WinPcap wrapper/translation for Delphi.

Comment: I looked for one of those as did the OP, I don't know if anybody ported these wrapper functions but as they all look like basic C dll exports, anybody with basic ability to read C declarations should be able to write the Delphi wrappers.

Comment: You need to do some research first to develop some minimal level of understanding of the subject. Overhead of sniffer just to forge some packets makes very few sense, really.

Comment: We have some old DOS machines that were instructed by 3rd party app via RAW packets. I have those raw packets sniffed, so I know what I need to send out, and I know it needs to be RAW because they used to put data right after mac address, and that can only be done via RAW packet. I have all my code written in Delphi. I know this can and is done using pcap in C#.  I did search for anything to put that in Delphi before digging in inventing the wheel all over again, but nothing came up. So I asked here if anyone knows the answer...

Comment: Why do you need WinPCAP to send messages over raw sockets? Just use raw socket directly (provided you have permissions).

Comment: Using Overbyte library to access raw sockets with WSocket failed for 3 of the adapters I tried to use, for receiving part, and I've later read that it does not work with all adapters, and thereforr quit that as an option. Do you have any further informations for sending part?

Comment: Indy have raw capability readily available, for example.

Comment: @ThatMarc, are you permissioned for raw socket operations?

Comment: @Free Consulting - without valid sender's address we are not allowed to send raw udp packets ever since XP afaik (which is what I need...), meanwhile TCP is fully disabled.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I have all permisions on the system. Runned as Administrator...

Comment: @ThatMarc, Windows Firewall is interfering heavily with packet forging when enable, thanks to MS approach to network security. Windows 2000 was only version providing fully compliant stack.

Comment: It is thanks for security on one side, but a trouble on the other.
Regardless, the main question  still stands as is, and therefore I'm not changing it, but rather leave it to someone (maybe ultimately me, if I ever manage to do it) to answer. Thanks for the hints and thoughts so far though!